# Подскажите пожалуйста, есть таблица в ms sql с нарастающим итогом (value), как можно из этого столбца сделать столбец с данными часовыми?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понимаю нужно отнимать строки, от текущей предыдущую?

Comment: `value - LAG(value)`. Вот только у тебя дискретность не час, а полчаса.

Comment: А если ms sql 2005. Есть что то похожее в старых sql?

Answer (score 0):

Пример получения разности соседних значений, работоспособный на SQL Server 2005.

```
CREATE TABLE test (time INT, value INT);
INSERT INTO test VALUES
(1,2),(2,5),(3,4),(4,3),(5,7),(6,6),(7,3),(8,8),(9,4);
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| time | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 7 |
| 6 | 6 |
| 7 | 3 |
| 8 | 8 |
| 9 | 4 |

```
SELECT t1.time, t1.value, t1.value - t2.value delta
-- из этой копии берём текущее значение
FROM test t1
-- из этой копии берём предыдущее значение
LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t1.time > t2.time
-- проверяем, что нет промежуточных записей
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT NULL
  FROM test t3
  WHERE t1.time > t3.time
    AND t3.time > t2.time
);
```

| time | value | delta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | *null* |
| 2 | 5 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 | -1 |
| 4 | 3 | -1 |
| 5 | 7 | 4 |
| 6 | 6 | -1 |
| 7 | 3 | -3 |
| 8 | 8 | 5 |
| 9 | 4 | -4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eKr_YooV)

Comment: Все получилось, спасибо!